# CollectionViewController does not show searchbar and navigation bar

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm trying to follow along with a video course to implement photo gallery with Unsplash.

First I implemented UIViewController with searchbar and navigation bar in it

```
PhotoCollectionViewController: UIViewController
```

and manually adding searchbar and navigation bar

```
//MARK: - Nav bar inelkaar steken hier

private func setupNavigationBar(){
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "Photos"
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    titleLabel.textColor = .black
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: titleLabel)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addBarButtonItem, actionBarButtonItem]
}
```

and the same for searchbar

so I got the result as this:
[image]

after this the `PhotoCollectionViewController: UIViewController` inheritance seemed be wrong what I did, and I need to change it to UICollectionViewController

I make then another controller inherited from UICollectionViewController  with the same logic `PhotoCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController`

It compiles without any issues, but I don't see navigation an search bar anymore

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: what happens if you pull the view  down ?

Comment: hello, nothing, searchbar and navigation are not hiding in the sliding menu

Answer (score 0):

May be your collectionView is hiding search bar and navigation bar. check collectionView constraints. (specially top anchor)

// PS: I could comment, but I don't have 50 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

1. Check the top constraint first of your collectionView. And maybe you can add this code to you viewDidLoad() :

   `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`
2. if you use ScollView at fullscreen (SuperView), you can use this :

   `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`
3. for searchBar IBOutlet you can add this :

   `searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`